# how to create a DBA user, role and profile in sqldeveloper?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

hey guys i am a beginner sql user , currently learning in sqldeveloper.

i am having issues with creating users, assigning roles , and profiles.
    here are the steps i took

first i created the user

```
create user bob
identified by password;
grant connect to bob;
grant all privileges to bob;
```

// since its the database admin it requires all privileges

```
CREATE PROFILE system_admin LIMIT
SESSIONS_PER_USER 2
CPU_PER_SESSION 10000
IDLE_TIME 60
CONNECT_TIME 480;
```

//created profile

```
CREATE ROLE database_admin 
IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT database_admin TO bob;
//then i assigned the role
```

i get error messages saying conflicts with another user or role name;
how would you guys create a DBA user , role and profile ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma after `CREATE ROLE database_admin`.  The `IDENTIFIED BY password` clause should be part of the same statement.